# How to properly make H\alpha without the space in between?

Tags: math-mode

I am trying to talk about the H$\alpha$ line in my article, but overleaf insists on adding a space in between the H and the \alpha. How does one fix that?

```
\newcommand{\halpha} {
  \ion{H}{$\alpha$}}
```

Ah sorry, I did not know that ion was part of my cls file.

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\ion}[2]{\textup{#1\,\textsc{\lowercase{#2}}}}
\newcommand*\element[1][]{%
  \def\aa@element@tr{#1}%
  \aa@element
}
```

Comment: Where is `\ion` from?

Comment: the code you show is forcing a space before the H, perhaps your `\ion` command that you do not show is also adding spaces, impossible to say without seeing the code.

Comment: You might also try `$\mathrm{H}\alpha$`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the `mhchem` package to get the correct upright H. Like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\begin{document}
   H\nobreakdash-alpha or \ce{H\alpha}
\end{document}
```

[image: H alpha]